Can we know from an enumator if a language is finite?
In this theorem:

When proving, in the direction from enumerators to decidable languages. The proof I know is as follows:

But how can one knows if langague L is finite or not, as we only have an enumerator for this language, and I don't think an enumator halts (or should halt) if the language is finite?

One cannot. The theorem does not say "given an enumerator, we can compute a TM that decides $L$".

Ah yes, I see it now. Thank you!
